# Why is jQuery's $.each so fast?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have to parse a lot of XML data to objects. I thought of three ways to get this XML to an object:

**XML**

```
<myXml>
  <tag1 val = "someVal"/>
  <tag2 val = "someVal"/>
  <tag3 val = "someVal"/>
</myXml>
```

**Option 1: using .find()**

```
var xml = getMyXml();
var myObj = {
   1 : xml.find('tag1').attr('val'),
   2 : xml.find('tag2').attr('val'),
   3 : xml.find('tag3').attr('val'),
}
```

**Option 2: using .each()**

```
var xml = getMyXml();
var myObj = {
   1 : 'tag1',
   2 : 'tag2',
   3 : 'tag3',
}
$.each(myObj, function(i,e){
  myObj[i] = xml.find(e).attr('val');
});
```

**Option 3: array**

```
var xml = getMyXml();
var myArr = ['tag1','tag2','tag3']
var myObj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
 myObj[i] = xml.find(myArr[i]).attr('val');
}
```

Using this perf http://jsperf.com/each-vs-arraysdfsdf  **option 2** was 82% faster than both other options. Why?

Comment: Bizarre. I would have expected the unwound options 1 to be fastest as it avoids any additional overhead.

Comment: I have no understanding of how things work underneath, but my only guess is that in option 1 it is rebuilding the object every time? However I am even more confused with option 3 being the same speed as option 1.

Comment: Must be optimising the content of the each callback, but I have not clue at this point. Anyone else got any ideas?

Comment: The [source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.each) might lend some insight. Looks like `(for item in object)` might just be faster than a `for i` loop. Probably worth adding it to the test.

Comment: @Jack: If anything I would now almost certainly expect `$.each` to be slower. Must be magic! :)

Comment: Amusingly this site suggests using loops instead of `$.each`: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It could just that looping over the properties of an object is faster than looping through the items of an array with a traditional for loop, but I'm no expert on javascript engines so who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mix array and jquery, simply use pure javascript functions with array, then result is completely different and way too faster. With jquery each the selector overhead is optimized may be that's reason it was faster with your test case.

```
var len = digitalArr.length; //Cache the length
var i = 0;
for (; i < len ; i++) {
  obj[i] = xmlobj.getElementsByTagName(''+digitalArr[i]+'')[0].getAttribute('val');
}
```

Check the jsperf result [here](http://jsperf.com/each-vs-arraysdfsdf/2)

Comment: That makes more sense. But why is option 1 still so slow?

Comment: I was wondering too, found some articles and here is a good one https://developers.google.com/v8/design?csw=1#prop_access . The property access  has a lot of overhead. Every time you add a property a new hidden class is created based on previous property and then updating it's value.